# React Navigation: move directly to last page and onBack go to previous screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

In [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/), How can I able to go directly to the last page and When `BackButton` pressed,
 go back to the previous screens.

Let me explain clearly,

Users can able to add new forms by tapping the 'Add' button. In my case, the user has to navigate 3 pages to create a new form.

**Example for Add:**

`ListPage` ---> `Page1` ---> `Page2` ----> `Page3`(send to api)

This works fine.

User can able to `edit` the submitted forms from the list page. So if the user taps the list item, it has to move directly to `Page3`, then when the `BackButton` is pressed it has to come to `Page2` then `Page1` then `ListPage`.

**Example for Edit:**

`ListPage` ----directnavigation----> `Page3` ----backpressed----> `Page2` ----backpressed----> `Page1` ----backpressed----> `ListPage`

How do I handle this in the `edit` scenario?

Comment: can i suggest something? why dont you create your own custom header and there at arrow click just navigate to that page, and disable your default navigation header

Comment: I'm sorry, you didn't understand my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using `StackActions`.

Here is the code,

```
  StackActions.reset({
    index: 2,
    key: undefined,
    actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Page1' }),
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Page2' }),
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Page3' })
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I donno whether you have been using React Header or native base header. But here I am showing an example where I used native base header with React navigation

```
    <Container>
                    <Header androidStatusBarColor={Constants.primary} hasTabs style={[Styles.header]}>
                        <Left style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack()} style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                <Icon name="ios-arrow-back" style={[Styles.headerLeftIcon]} />
                                <Text style={[Styles.headerLeftText]}>Go Back</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </Left>
<Container>
```

This is the basic code where user goes back on back arrow click using props.navigation.goBack().

So for your scenario I would suggest you to send a param to the 3rd page (Ex: type: 'edit'). So when user clicks back button check the type and if its not edit do the basic props.navigation.goBack() or if its edit go for props.navigation.navigate('Second Page').

Because basically routes work like push and pop so if we got directly to page3, page1 and page2 are not part of routes array, so we should show it a path to go for page 2 from page3 on back button click

Comment: Well In this case, if you move from Page 3 to Page 2 using props.navigation.navigate('Second Page'). It'll add it to the stack . I'm looking here is like backstack in android. My expectation is like dynamically launch 3rd screen. And when back is pressed, screen2 and screen 1.

Comment: There is nothing like that and the routing stack works only in the way u push the routes and conditional rendering is only possible at that instance

Comment: I fixed it by using StackActions.

Comment: Thats great post ur answer if possible so that it helps others

Answer (score 0):

react-native have a best way to solve your scenario. please use **this.props.navigation.dispatch(screen-name);**.

refer this link `https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html`

Comment: const navigateToPage3 = NavigationActions.navigate({
                routeName: 'Page1',
                params: { smsData: data },
                action: NavigationActions.navigate({
                    routeName: 'Page2',
                    action: NavigationActions.navigate({
                        routeName: 'Page3'
                    })
                })
            });
            this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateToPage3);

Comment: It navigates to Page1 and its stopped

Comment: I fixed it using StackActions. Thanks